# What Android Studio/Gradle do what Eclipse/adt can't to avoid: "Exception while inflating <vector>"

Tags: android, eclipse, vector, adt, compatibility

When I'm using AppCompatActivity and other android support libs stuff, work and build an app using Eclipse/ADT, it's working just fine on modern devices.
However when I'm trying to run app on older(Android 4.x etc) devices it crashes with the exception:

```
Exception while inflating <vector>
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17<vector> tag requires viewportWidth > 0
at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateStateFromTypedArray
```

Guess it happen due to lack of native support of vector graphics on the older devices.

However when I build and run similar app on the Android Studio/Gradle it works fine even on the older devices.

To resolve it I found bunch of advices like using

```
static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

It does not help me.

Also I found advice to use this param:

```
 vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

But I have no idea where can I use it with ADT?

Another good advice was to update the libs to the latest ones:
I'm using the latest (25.3.1) support libs like appcompat-v7, design and all dependencies I get from the pom files in the google repository.

Compared the generated manifests. But found nothing which could make Eclipse to build the workable apk for the older devices.

Nothing can help with.

What should I add/change to make the ADT build apk not affected with "Exception while inflating " on older devices?

Please note that migration to Android Studio(or conversion projects to gradle) is not an option for me now.
Question is what else I have to do in Eclipse/ADT project.

Thank you.

Comment: Error says, your `viewPortWidth` is `0` or less than `0`. It must be greater than zero

Comment: Any ideas how can I fix it? 
I did not set viewPortWidth and there is no such problem on new devices.

Comment: I just found that eclipse apk abc_vector_text.xml does not have the attr like android:viewportWidth="24.0" which is present in the original appcompat-v7 library. Also the path tag inside it is empty as well.
The Android Studio apk however has good abc_vector_text.xml
So why ADT strips down the original library drawing resource? Is there some way to make it keep library resources as is?